# How to change tabset nav-pills background colour using [ngClass] or customClass

Tags: html, css, angular6, ng-class

I am using angular-7, 
I want to change the colour of tab depending on the validation, i have added customClass where i am checking if timesheet is valid or not, if it is invalid i want to change the nav-pills color to red, else normal

I have tried to write code below  but is not working
Can you please help me to solve this issue.

```
<div class="col">
     <tabset type="pills">
       <tab [heading]="strings.timesheetHeading"
          [customClass]="isTimesheetFormInvalid() ? 'invalid-timesheet-expense-tab' : ''">
          <pace-timesheet [model]="model.timesheetEntries" [parentForm]="timesheetFormChildren"></pace-timesheet>
        </tab>

        <tab [heading]="strings.expensesHeading"
                     [customClass]="isExpenseFormInvalid() ? 'invalid-timesheet-expense-tab' : ''">
              <pace-expenses [model]="model" [parentForm]="expensesFormChildren"></pace-expenses>
        </tab>
     </tabset>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .nav-pills > li.tab.invalid-timesheet-expense-tab.active > a,
  .nav-pills > li.tab.invalid-timesheet-expense-tab.active > a:hover,
  .nav-pills > li.tab.invalid-timesheet-expense-tab.active > a:focus {
    background-color: $common-color-error-red;

    heading {
      color: $common-color-white;
    }
  }

  .nav-pills > li.tab.invalid-timesheet-expense-tab > a,
  .nav-pills > li.tab.invalid-timesheet-expense-tab > a:hover,
  .nav-pills > li.tab.invalid-timesheet-expense-tab > a:focus {

    heading {
      color: $common-color-error-red;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" [ngClass]="{'bg-red': isTimesheetFormInvalid == true,'bg-green': isTimesheetFormInvalid == false}" formControlName="test">
```

Add conditional class using ngClass and add your condition as per your requirements I did same thing before using ngb-tabset.

I hope this will help.